# Azure AD B2C - SinglePage Application - Custom policies - Claim missing when refreshing token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We've set up Azure AD B2C with custom policies and configured social providers. We used the starter pack as starting point. As we needed the email address, we also added this claim to the various technical profiles

```
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
```

This all works fine, the email address is in the idToken.

We use MSAL JS in our app and call `acquireTokenSilent` to get a token after a user is logged in. After 1 hour, it will refresh the token, as expected. However, that token is missing the email claim in the idToken.

Which profile should I update? I saw the TechnicalProfile with name `RefreshTokenReadAndSetup` which has the following comment:

```
<!--Requirement: Claims that you return in the relying party technical profile output claims
            that are not stored in Azure AD B2C, must be added to the output claims collection here-->
          <!--
```

Not sure what I should add there though, and is this the right location?

Comment: Try adding  `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />` in output claims of **RefreshTokenReadAndSetup** technical profile. Check this [reference](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/refresh-token-journey/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_RefreshTokenJourney.xml).

Comment: @Sridevi unfortunately, that didn't work. The email is still empty. Another thing I noticed is that the "scp" property is missing. We initially had issues that the email was missing from the original token as well, and we added a custom scope "license" to fix that. The scp property is present on the original token, but not on the refreshed token. Also, do I need to update other TechnicalProfiles to perhaps add the email as outputclaim or persistedclaim?